# Google script Multiple criteria in same row and validation of value in previous row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm starting with a script that someone here graciously helped with and need to build onto it and do not know where to start. Here is the current script:

```
function yourFunction(){
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var rg=sh.getDataRange();//columns are fruit,status and then cost.
var vA=rg.getValues();
for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
 if(vA[i][0].toString()=='Apple' && vA[i][1].toString()=='Ripe' && vA[i][2].toString=='Large' && vA[i][4].toString=''){
  vA[i][4]=5.5;
  }
 }
  rg.setValues(vA);//This writes all of the data at one time.
}
```

What I would like to add to this is a second set of criteria that looks at another column value = Lot Number(Column D). Assuming that the current Lot Number is the same as the previous row's and where all the above match, each additional rows will be a set value 3. But if the value of the Lot Number before the current row is not the same, then the value is 5. In what I've read, there may need to be some looping condition in this so the calculations don't keep going on and on. Any help here would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Here is a link to a basic format of the spreadsheet [Test Script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FrRzq1IDn1OG2QJHzAFg9JpCsIUQGHcqgWm_IIt-BqM/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Can you open access to the spreadsheet?

Comment: Sorry about that. Just opened it up to the public. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your explanation of your desired logic is not clear. "and where all of the above match", what exactly do you mean by "all of the above"?  "each additional rows will be a set value 3", what is being set to 3?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated function that demonstrates the general approach for what I believe you're describing.

```
var COLUMNS = {
  FRUIT: 0,
  STATUS: 1,
  SIZE: 2,
  LOT_NUMBERr: 3,
  COST: 4,
  NEW_VALUE: 5,
}

function updateValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var previousLotNumber = -1;
  for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++){

    if (values[i][COLUMNS.FRUIT] == 'Apple'
        && values[i][COLUMNS.STATUS] == 'Ripe') {
      values[i][COLUMNS.COST] = 5.5; 
    }

    if (previousLotNumber == values[i][COLUMNS.LOT_NUMBER]) {
      values[i][COLUMNS.NEW_VALUE] = 3;
    } else {
      values[i][COLUMNS.NEW_VALUE] = 5;
    }
    previousLotNumber = values[i][COLUMNS.LOT_NUMBER];
  }
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

After running this function, this sheet looks like the following:

```
+--------+-----------+--------+------------+------+-----------+
| Fruit  |  Status   |  Size  | Lot Number | Cost | New Value |
+--------+-----------+--------+------------+------+-----------+
| Apple  | Ripe      | Large  |        101 |  5.5 |         5 |
| Apple  | Ripe      | Medium |        101 |  5.5 |         3 |
| Apple  | Ripe      | Large  |        103 |  5.5 |         5 |
| Apple  | Not Ready | Large  |        102 |      |         5 |
| Apple  | Not Ready | Medium |        101 |      |         5 |
| Banana | Ripe      | Large  |        201 |      |         5 |
| Orange | Ripe      | Large  |        301 |      |         5 |
| Orange | Not Ready | Medium |        301 |      |         3 |
| Pear   | Ripe      | Large  |        401 |      |         5 |
+--------+-----------+--------+------------+------+-----------+
```

A few notes:

- use descriptive variable names
- use a set of constants to provide descriptive names for the columns
- for your ask, all you need to do is use a variable to store the previous rows lot number, no additional looping complexity required